# Shorthand for defining PyParsing field names

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a few pyparsing tokens defined as follows:

```
field = Word(alphas + "_").setName("field")
```

Is there really no shorthand for this?

Furthermore, this does not seem to work, the dictionary returned by `expression.parseString()`  is always an empty one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing `setName` and `setResultsName`. `setName` assigns a name to the expression so that exception messages are more meaningful. Compare:

```
>>> integer1 = Word(nums)
>>> integer1.parseString('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing-1.5.6-py2.6.egg\pyparsing.py", line 1032, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(0123...) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

and:

```
>>> integer2 = Word(nums).setName("integer")
>>> integer2.parseString('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing-1.5.6-py2.6.egg\pyparsing.py", line 1032, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected integer (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

`setName` gives a name to the expression itself.

`setResultsName` on the other hand gives a name to the parsed data that is returned, like named fields in a regex.

```
>>> expr = integer.setResultsName('age') + integer.setResultsName('credits')
>>> data = expr.parseString('20 110')
>>> print data.dump()
['20', '110']
- age: 20
- credits: 110
```

And as @Kimvais has mentioned, there *is* a shortcut for `setResultsName`:

```
>>> expr = integer('age') + integer('credits')
```

Note also that `setResultsName` returns a copy of the expression - that is the only way that using the same expression multiple times with different names works.

Comment: A common request, but that is a Python issue, not a pyparsing one. `expr = Word(nums); number=expr` Now number and expr both point to the same expression.  Now do `expr.parseString('123')` the object does *not* know what its own name is, and trying to walk through `locals()` to find out will give both `expr` and `number`.

Answer (score 3):

`field = Word(alphas + "_")("field")`

seems to work.